# Can't deserialize from derrived class

Tags: c#, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I have the following class:

```
public class Label
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }

    public Label(){}
}
```

The `List<Field>` can contain derrived classes from `Field`, for example:

```
public class Image : Field
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    int Xpos { get; set; }
    int Ypos { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I use the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Label>
    <Name>test</Name>

    <Fields>
        <Image></Image>
    </Fields>
</Label>
```

My deserialization code:

```
string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "Label_1.xml");
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Label), new XmlRootAttribute("Label"));
Label result;

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xmlString))
{
    result = (Label)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

And I deserialize it, the `Field` property from a `Label` only has the `Field` in it, not the `Image`. How can I get the derrived class Image to be added in the list of Fields? Now I'm only able to add Field classes and the Images are being ignored. Thanks for help!

**EDIT**

If I change my code to the following:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Image))]
public abstract class Field
{
    int Xpos { get; set; }
    int Ypos { get; set; }
    int Zindex { get; set; }
    Style Style { get; set; }
}
```

Nothing happens! :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# XML serialization of derived classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326481/c-sharp-xml-serialization-of-derived-classes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick

```
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Field", Type = typeof(Field))]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Image", Type = typeof(Image))]
    public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks. This tag `represents an attribute that specifies the derived types that the XmlSerializer can place in a serialized array`, from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) ... where the serialized array is the above List

Answer (score 1):

Make `Field` **abstract**, implement it on `Image` and use the [XmlIncludeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Image))]
public abstract class Field
{
    int Xpos; 
    int Ypos; 
}
```

Comment: Did that but it's not being added

Comment: Try serialize it first and see what the XML should be